# correctly set page size for KOMA single A3 page in an A4 report

Tags: margins, geometry, typearea

I've a problem with a single A3 page in an A4 report document.

The problem is the position of the content that is placed in an A4 area (red line in the image) at the top-left corner of the A3 page.

[image: A3 page with A4 area inside]Hi

This is the code I used to intert a single A3 page. The \newgeometry command works but referred to the "virtual" A4 page at the top-left corner of the new A3 page so the final positions of the content (header, graph and pagenumber) are wrong.

```
\afterpage{ % Insert after the current page
\clearpage

\KOMAoptions{paper=a3}
\recalctypearea
\newgeometry{
 %total={297mm,420mm},
 a3paper,
 left=20mm,
 top=40mm,
 tmargin=30mm,
 bottom=20mm,
 right=20mm
}
%
\begin{figure}[p]
    \centering
    \digraph{VacuumCallGraph}{
    rankdir=LR
    ratio=fill
    size="7,9!"
    %size="10,14!"
    margin=0
    V_TF_ControlLoop [label=<<b >V_TF_ControlLoop</b>> color=black height=.8 width=1.1]
    ...
}
\caption{Vacuum functions call graph}
\end{figure}

\clearpage
\KOMAoptions{paper=A4,pagesize}
\recalctypearea
}
\restoregeometry
```

Anyone can help to set properly the A3 geometry in order to fill all the A3 area ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Add option `usegeometry` to the options of the KOMA-Script class.